# Creating bootstrap glow buttons with correct color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to give my bootstrap buttons a glow effect. I know I can use box-shadow for this, but since it requires a color specified, I was hoping there was some way I could inherit it from the button itself, so that each different button (success, primary, warning, etc) glowed with its respective color. For example, here's what it would look like for btn-primary, but I'd like to make the color dynamically inherited:

```css
.glow-button {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px #007bff;
}

.btn-lg {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudo element where you apply filter can do this relying on inheriting the background color:

```css
.glow-button {
  position:relative;
}
.glow-button::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:inherit;
  filter:blur(15px);
  transition:0.5s;
}

.glow-button:focus::before {
   filter:blur(1px);
}

.btn-lg {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-success">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-danger">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-warning">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-info">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-light">Light</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-dark">Dark</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems very clever. I'm a real CSS novice so this is a bit greek to me, but it clearly works, I'm impressed. It looks like you're basically implementing the box-shadow yourself, allowing you to inherit the color. Thanks!

Comment: Done! Thanks again for your innovative solution. I'm still hoping there's a simpler way that doesn't require re-implementing box-shadow, but for now this looks like the best way to do it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ultimately came up with. If someone has a way to do it without manually specifying the color for each button type I'd love to hear it!

```css
.glow-button {
  --box-shadow-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px var(--box-shadow-color);
}

.btn-primary.glow-button {
  --box-shadow-color: #007bff;
}

.btn-secondary.glow-button {
  --box-shadow-color: #6c757d;
}

.btn-success.glow-button {
  --box-shadow-color: #28a745;
}

.btn-danger.glow-button {
  --box-shadow-color: #dc3545;
}

.btn-warning.glow-button {
  --box-shadow-color: #ffc107;
}

.btn-info.glow-button {
  --box-shadow-color: #17a2b8;
}

.btn-light.glow-button {
  --box-shadow-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.btn-dark.glow-button {
  --box-shadow-color: #343a40;
}

.btn-lg {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="form-group">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-primary">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-success">Success</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-danger">Danger</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-warning">Warning</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-info">Info</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-light">Light</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg glow-button btn-dark">Dark</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if by any chance you are using scss you could set your colors in a map and then just iterate and generate the classes
https://frontstuff.io/generate-all-your-utility-classes-with-sass-maps

Comment: I'm not currently, but not opposed to it. But based on that article, it looks like I'd have to still specify the colors manually, wouldn't I? Either that, or use scss to modify Bootstrap itself?

Comment: Yes. you will have to add your set manually. Or you could work with the source of bootstrap and then you have access to the color map from bootstrap